# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.LoaderStrategyException: Can't find strategy (('lazy', 'True') for Student.student_qn

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Am trying to create (one to many relationship between three tables) where the Student table is able to extend its id to the (StudentQuestion and Mark)tables respectivley. But i get an error concerning the (Lazy=True) argument from the student table and failing to understand why!!

```
from datetime import datetime
from ..utils.db import db



class Student(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(255),  nullable=True, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    student_qn = db.relationship('StudentQuestion', backref='examinee', lazy='True')
    student_mark = db.relationship('Mark', backref='mark')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Student('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()


class Mark(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    percentage_mark = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    grade = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('student.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Mark('{self.percentage_mark}','{self.grade}')"

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()


class StudentQuestion(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    passage = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    passage_question = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date_qn_attempt = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    answer = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('student.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"StudentQuestion('{self.passage}','{self.passage_question}', '{self.date_qn_attempt}','{self.answer}')"

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Try `lazy=True`. (as a boolean value instead of a string)

Comment: Thank you @PatrickYoder. This worked but leaves me asking "why does it refuse the lazy argument in string format!!"

Comment: I believe this is because there are only four(six) options for this parameter, and `'True'` is not one of them. [This article](https://medium.com/@ns2586/sqlalchemys-relationship-and-lazy-parameter-4a553257d9efhttps://medium.com/@ns2586/sqlalchemys-relationship-and-lazy-parameter-4a553257d9ef) explains it well.

Answer (score 0):

The defined relationship requires the parameter **lazy** to be a boolean. Not a string, as provided in the question.

Change this row:

```py
student_qn = db.relationship('StudentQuestion', backref='examinee', lazy='True')
```

To:

```py
student_qn = db.relationship('StudentQuestion', backref='examinee', lazy=True)
```